# How can I dry out this partial rendering in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= render '/notifications/notification', notification: notification %>
```

That's a lot of notification. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess there's no problem, unless you have that same line more than once in your code. Anyways, try passing just the notification object `<%= render notification %>`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and found that activemodel implements to_partial_path for this.